# Displaying list to textblock

Tags: c#, wpf

```
List<Data> DataList = Data.GetList();

foreach (var i in DataList)
{
    Txtblock1.Text = ToString(DataList);
}
```

I am simply trying to add the list contents of a customclass list to a textblock.
the list creates has several different data types thats why the ToString is there but that doesn't work.

EDIT: I should have said sorry but I have to do this for several classes, will overriding the ToString be sensible?

Comment: Care to share exactly *how* it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this:

```
Txtblock1.Text = string.Join("; ", DataList.Select(o => o.ToString()));
```

and then override `ToString` in the `Data` class to provide what you want. The separator could be anything, it could even be `Environment.NewLine`.

If you insist on using the `ToString` method you've built, it could be this:

```
Txtblock1.Text = string.Join("; ", DataList.Select(o => ToString(o)));
```

Comment: I don't insist on it, if there is an easier way I would be happy to hear it

Comment: @user3009379, the easier way is to `override` the `ToString` method on the `Data` class and just call `ToString()` on the instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
Txtblock1.Text += ToString(DataList);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to do here:

1) Override the ToString method in the Data Class:

```
public override string ToString()
```

In there create a string which contains the values of your objects you wish to display.  Don't forget to add Environment.NewLine at the end.

2) In your code above change as follows:

```
        List<Data> DataList = Data.GetList();

    foreach (var i in DataList)
    {
        Txtblock1.Text += i.ToString();
    }
```